# How to determine if a session with same variable is already there in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel framework. There is a function in controller that creates session with name `store_id`

StoreController.php

```
function initiate($id)
{
    //Some queries
    session['store_id' => 'some value'];
}
```

Now if I run this function on one tab then `session::get('store_id')` is going on. But if I open another tab in the same browser then again run the function that means `session('store_id')` will be again set. How do I handle this situation that if there is already a session then it should redirect to it's perspective url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay first of all, `Bruuuhhhh been there and done that`

Alright, lets begin. you want that if there is already a session with `store_id` going on then you want user to redirect or send back.

In your controller add this

```
public function initiate()
{
    if(session()->has('store_id'))
    {
        //What ever your logic
    }
    else
    {
        redirect()->to('/store')->withErrors(['check' => "You have session activated for here!."]);
    }
}
```

Most probably you would be wondering that user can just go to other url after `/store/other-urls` Yess he can.

To avoid this. Add a custom `middleware`

```
php artisan make:middleware SessionOfStore //You can name it anything.
```

In that middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->session()->has('store_id'))
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['privilege_check' => "You are not privileged to go there!."]);
    }
    return '/home';
}
```

in your main store page. Add an `anchor tag` `<a href="/stop">Stop Service</a>`

Now in your `web.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'SessionOfStore'], function()
{
    //Add your routes here.
    Route::get('/stop', 'StoreController@flushSession');
});
```

Now you have restrict access to urls and has checked the sessions.

Now in

```
public function flushSession()
{
    //empty out the session and
    return redirect()->to('/home');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel session helper has the function `has` to check this.

```
if (session()->has('store_id'))
{
    // Redirect to the store
}
else
{
    // Set the store id
}
```

[The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#using-the-session) contains all of the possible functions that can be used with the session helper.